# Android - make an arrow shape with xml

Tags: android, android-button, android-shape

I want to make a button for my shape like this one

[image]

Is there a way to do this with xml ?
Like setting some points, in my case I have 5..

Comment: if the background is dynamic of layout it shows its white lanes [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FKtR1.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FKtR1.png)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you need is to create a *`shape xml file`* in your project's *`drawable-xxx`* folder and then use this shape as background for a button.

Here is the shape file called *`arrow_shape.xml`*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Colored rectangle-->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size 
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="40dp" />
        <solid android:color="#5EB888" />
        <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- This rectangle for the top arrow edge -->
<!-- Its color should be the same as the layout's background -->
<item
    android:top="-40dp"
    android:bottom="65dp"
    android:right="-30dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<!-- This rectangle for the lower arrow edge -->
<!-- Its color should be the same as the layout's background -->
<item
    android:top="65dp"
    android:bottom="-40dp"
    android:right="-30dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Then use it as button's background, for example

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_shape"/>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

More info on *`Layer-List`* you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList).

**EDIT:**

Keep in mind though that I used certain values for the shape's width and height. If you change those you might need to change the values of the *`top, bottom and right attributes`*. So, in that case consider using different values in your project's *`values`* directory.

Answer (score 13):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:width="50dp" android:height="10dp" android:right="6dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:width="7dp" android:height="7dp"
        android:left="50dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="0"
            android:pivotY="0">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image: green arrow]

Answer (score 7):

With the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can just use the standard [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) defining the [**`shapeAppearanceOverlay`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) attribute:

Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button.Triangle"
      ...      />
```

And in your style define:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button.Triangle" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>

    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">50%</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add pressed state color without altering the shape ?

Comment: @ReejeshPK Yes. You can use the `app:backgroundTint` attribute. It works with a selector.