# Android: Make a button with triangle shape using xml definitions (drawable)

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-drawable, android-button

I want create this using button (TextView) by using XML definiton:

[image: my image]

In layout of the Activity I have:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_arrow" <!-- I NEED IMPLEMENT THIS -->
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="7dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/music_cloud"
        android:onClick="exportSong"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/export_upload"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_yellow_text_color"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I founded several posts:

[making-a-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517589/making-a-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions)

[Android triangle (arrow) defined as an XML shape](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/)

or [Android - make an arrow shape with xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143905/android-make-an-arrow-shape-with-xml)

I tried modify several XML definition but nothing was good. Is there some easy way how to implement this shape? Also it should have a transparent background.

Comment: xnl shapes are not a "general purpose" way of declaring all drawables one needs, try writing your custom android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape and use it with a ShapeDrawable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If someone still has issues with this :

1. xml:

   ```
   <item android:top="45dp">
       <shape>
           <size android:height="100dp" android:width="90dp"/>
           <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:top="36dp" android:left="11dp">
       <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="45"
           android:toDegrees="0"
           android:pivotX="80%"
           android:pivotY="20%" >
           <shape>
               <size android:width="40dp"
                   android:height="30dp"/>
               <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" android:width="1dp"/>
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
           </shape>
       </rotate>
   </item>
   </layer-list>
   ```
2. override TextView and use it in your layout:

   ```
   public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

       private int mWidth;
       private int mHeight;


       public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
           super(context, attrs);

       }

       @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

          super.onDraw(canvas);
           Paint mPaint = new Paint();
           int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.YourColor);

           mPaint.setColor(color);
           Path mPath = new Path();
           mPath.moveTo(.0f, this.getHeight());
           mPath.lineTo(0.8f * this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
           mPath.lineTo(this.getWidth(), 0.5f * this.getHeight());
           mPath.lineTo(0.8f * this.getWidth(), .0f);
           mPath.lineTo(.0f, .0f);
           mPath.lineTo(.0f, this.getHeight());

           canvas.clipPath(mPath);
           canvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaint);


       }
   }
   ```

Regarding the xml example: there are two rectangles overlapping.You have to play around with the values a lot and this makes it difficult to use on different views. I think using a custom view is the best solution in this case.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to breakdown and make a custom View.  Thanks for making a nice and simple example.

Comment: but seems like the text Property will be lost if we use your code !

Comment: Just put  super.onDraw(canvas); 
call at the end of onDraw Method , so that will make this code work properly

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it also using a [**`MaterialButton`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#material-button) included in the Material Components library.

Add the `MaterialButton` in your layout then:

- use the `app:icon` attribute to add an icon on the left
- apply the [style](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#icon-button) `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon` provided by the library
- define a custom shape using the [**`app:shapeAppearanceOverlay`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) attribute (it requires v.1.1.0)

Something like:

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        android:text="..."
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/CustomShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button"
        .../>
```

where the `shapeAppearanceOverlay` is defined in your `styles.xml`:

```
  <style name="CustomShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>

    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">18dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">18dp</item>
  </style>
```

The final result:

[image]

Comment: Where we find cornerFamily at all

Comment: @ShivamKumar It requires material components v.1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

```
<item>
    <inset android:insetBottom="2dp" >
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item android:state_pressed="true">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <corners android:radius="3dip" />

                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dip"
                        android:color="#5e7974" />

                    <gradient
                        android:angle="-90"
                        android:centerColor="#ECEFF1"
                        android:endColor="#FFAB00"
                        android:startColor="#FFAB00" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:state_focused="true">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <corners android:radius="3dip" />

                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dip"
                        android:color="#5e7974" />

                    <gradient
                        android:angle="-90"
                        android:centerColor="#ECEFF1"
                        android:endColor="#FFAB00"
                        android:startColor="#FFAB00" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <corners android:radius="3dip" />

                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dip"
                        android:color="#5e7974" />

                    <gradient
                        android:angle="-90"
                        android:centerColor="#ECEFF1"
                        android:endColor="#FFD600"
                        android:startColor="#FFD600" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </inset>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="65dp"
    android:right="-129dp"
    android:top="-40dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="50" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/background_color_light_yellow" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="-40dp"
    android:right="-129dp"
    android:top="65dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="-50" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/background_color_light_yellow" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```