# Round arrow shape button

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, shapes

Right now I have this button using Shape Theming which I got from this thread.

[Android: Make a button with triangle shape using xml definitions (drawable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264101/android-make-a-button-with-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions-drawable)

Code:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button.Triangle" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">4dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">4dp</item>
        <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">50%</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">50%</item>
</style>
```

But I need the rounded edges like this button on all the corners of the triangle

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Ask the graphic designer for this background vector image.

Comment: I understand that this is not an option because the final part of the button, of the triangle, must always have the same width. What should be variable is the rectangular part.

Answer (score 0):

Add shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:width="150dp" android:height="50dp" android:right="6dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:topRightRadius="4dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:width="35dp"
    android:height="35dp"
    android:left="148dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="44"
        android:pivotX="0"
        android:pivotY="0">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
                android:topRightRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"/>
        </shape>

    </rotate>
</item></layer-list>
```

Comment: My button need a match parent width. Your solution have a static 150dp width