# Rectangle Shape with Arrow using XML

Tags: android, xml

How to implement this shape of `Departments` header using `shape` and `xml` without 9-patch ?

I mean rectangle with arrow on the left.

[image]

My code snippet:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="1px"
        android:left="@dimen/edittext_border"
        android:right="@dimen/edittext_border"
        android:top="@dimen/edittext_border">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/edittext_border_width"
                android:color="@color/menu_divider" />

            <solid android:color="@color/background" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />


        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: It is not possible..!! You can use vector instead..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya I'm newbie in android and I found that I can do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143905/android-make-an-arrow-shape-with-xml

But because of my small experience, I can't refactor this answer to my needs

Comment: It is not same as you want..!! As per my understanding `layer-list` cannot make the shape you want..!!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311785/android-drawing-custom-shapes) for some explanation

Comment: I think this can be done. How tall is the Departments view supposed to be? And is the background of it white or transparent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you are looking for someting like this, try the following code..

[image: Final Output]

1. Make a xml arrow_shape in your drawable folder.

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item>
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45" android:toDegrees="45"  
      android:pivotX="-40%" android:pivotY="87%" >
       <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
           <stroke android:color="#c6802a" android:width="10dp"/>
           <solid android:color="#c6802a" />
       </shape>
   </rotate>
   </item>
   </layer-list>
   ```
2. Make a xml rectangle_shape in your drawable folder.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="#B2E3FA" />
    </shape>
   </item>
   ```
3. In your main xml file

   ```
   <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:gravity="center"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   tools:context="com.example.stpl.myapplication.MainActivity">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/arrow"
       android:layout_width="30dp"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:background="@drawable/arrow_shape"
       android:rotation="270" />

     <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/rectangle"
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: add corner radius in the rectangle, as in @VLeonovs photo

Answer (score 1):

A solution with a gradient:

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item android:width="2dp" android:height="2dp"
      android:top="4dp" android:left="3dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="0"
        android:pivotY="0">
      <shape>
        <solid android:color="#D83945"/>
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
  <item android:width="50dp" android:height="11dp" android:left="3dp">
    <shape>
      <gradient
          android:startColor="#D83945"
          android:endColor="#F9700C"
          />
      <corners
          android:radius="2dp"
          />
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

The final result is:

[image: arrow shape with gradient]